# How to create the tslib file when the error reads "Unable to open tslib.pyx: File not Found"?

Tags: python, pandas, finance, pandas-datareader

I am trying to pull finance data from online using pandas and pandas-datareader and a key file in the program seems to be missing.

I have tried creating the file and continuing but I have no idea what this code is supposed to do so that did not work. I have tried uninstalling pandas, pandas-datareadr, in conda install and pip install. I have tried re-installing all of ananconda and visual studio code to no avail.

```
import datetime as dt 
now = dt.datetime.now()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import pandas as pd 
import pandas_datareader.data as web

style.use('ggplot')
start = dt.datetime(2010,1,1)
end = dt.datetime.now
df = web.DataReader('IIPR', 'yahoo', start, end)
print(df.head)
```

ERROR

(base) C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\Python>cd c:\Users\Chris\Desktop\Python && cmd /C "set "PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8" && set "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1" && C:\Users\Chris\Anaconda3\python.exe c:\Users\Chris.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py
--default --client --host localhost --port 55519 c:\Users\Chris\Desktop\Python\FinanceBasics.py "
Backend Qt5Agg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.

Unable to open 'tslib.pyx': File not found (file:///c:/users/chris/desktop/python/pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx).

I expect the code to create a data frame with finance data pulled from yahoo (I also understand that there are some problems with yahoo finance API and others but I have not been able to arrive at the step in my code).

Comment: You've got an installation problem. Note pandas is in c:/users/chris/desktop/python/pandas and python in C:\Users\Chris\Anaconda3\. How did you install pandas? There should be a pandas within Anaconda3 as well.

Comment: I use "conda install". I have realized that conda comes with pandas and have deleted everything and re-installed. My python files are stored in that python file but the program is stored in another location. Could that be causing the problem? Do I need to move my scripts into my path?

Comment: You have many options. Generally you make sure python (from Anaconda3) dir is in your path (and make sure no other Python is) then give the path to your script as the argument to python. VSCode may do this for you, I am not familiar.